# Handling layouts using nested Vue.js components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

We have been using Vue.js at my company for the last few months and we're really liking it! We are using Element UI for the UI and vue-router for routing. Based on the structure of our data, we nest our routes several layers deep. It looks something like this:

```
App -> 
    Line ->
        Type ->
            Component1
            Component2
            Component3
```

Our designer would like to be able to control layouts on a per-page basis, even all the way down inside of `Component*`. For instance, in `Component1` there may be a layout with a sidebar and footer and in `Component2` there would be no sidebar but the footer would be hidden.

We've found this complicated based on the nested structure. Instead of components showing up as distinct blocks on a page they are nested inside of each other. We could un-nest each Vue route, but then we run the risk of duplicating logic through a lot of the pages that are at the same level.

What's are some good ways to handle layouts in a nested structure such as this?

Comment: Have you looked into the concept of `slots` and whether or not they would be appropriate for your use case?

Comment: Like the above said, slots may work. Alternatively, you can also pass multiple components to the `route` that you define in order to control which components appear in the page.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like layouts are being specified independently of component build, so you would want to make it as orthogonal as possible.

Additional data can be added to routes in the `meta` property.

```js
const routes = [
  { 
    path: '/', 
    name: 'Home', 
    component: Home,
    meta: { hiddenFeatures: {sidebar: true, footer: false} }
  },
  ...
```

On App component, watch for route changes and set visibility flags based on the additional configuration.

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      hiddenFeatures: {}
    };
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': function (route) {
      this.hiddenFeatures = route.meta.hiddenFeatures || {}
    }
  },
}
```

In the App template, use conditional rendering

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <sidebar v-if="!hiddenFeatures.sidebar"></sidebar>
```

By getting the logic the right way round, you can avoid having to add properties to every single route, just (e.g) those you want to hide.

Comment: To prevent the possible issue because of the incorrect initial value of `hiddenFeatures` of  data, instead of `hiddenFeatures: {}` it must be init with `hiddenFeatures: this.$route.meta.hiddenFeatures || {}`.